# Typescript Regex - checks only first charactcer

Tags: regex, typescript

I am trying to validate a string using typescript RegEx, but my RegEx is checking only the first character and ignores the remaining characters. This is my code.

```
const regEx = new RegExp('[0-9A-Za-z_\\-`~!@#$%^&*()=+ ]+');
```

The above expression validates "{abc" but not "a}bc".

Please help.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I don't actually see curly braces in your character class at all.  What is the logic behind what you are trying to match/validate?

Comment: My regular exp should allow only the characters which are available in the expression. But the check is occurring only for the first character.

Comment: There is no TypeScript in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add anchors to your regex:

```
const regEx = new RegExp('^[0-9A-Za-z_\\-`~!@#$%^&*()=+ ]+$');
//                     ___^                             __^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand that ^ to $ denotes start to end of the string. Now this is allowing only the characters which are mentioned in the expression except backslah (\). But that is allowed as per the expression.